# pymf factorization solution sorted?

Tags: python, numpy, variance, factorization

I try apply a matrix factorization on my dataset by using [`pymf` module](http://code.google.com/p/pymf/). As described in the example on the `pymf` site, I use `non-negative matrix factorization`, so I get some `W`- and `H`-matrices. How can I make sure, that the `W`-vectors are being returned ordered by variance explained? I couldn't find it in the manual and in all my testing it has been so. I would like to avoid sorting them again, if it is already done.

If it is *not*: Is there a generally *fastest* way?

I thought of something like either

```
let X approx= dot(W,H)
for k in arange(0,W[:,0].size):
    variance[k] = abs(dot(W[k],H[k])**2
X-variance
```

or

```
let X approx= dot(W,H)
variances = var(dot(X,W),axis=0)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code of pymf non negative factorization](http://code.google.com/p/pymf/source/browse/trunk/lib/pymf/nmf.py), I see no option for sorting the vectors by variance.